# Issue with Requesting OAuth Access Token

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, linkedin-api, coldfusion-9, access-token

I'm working on building a library for a client to integrate with LinkedIn's API and am currently working on the OAuth implementation. I am able to request the initial token's no problem and have the user grant the authentication to my app, but when I try to request the access token with the oauth_token and oauth_verifier (along with the rest of the oauth information that I send with ever request, I get a signature invalid error.

The OAuth settings that I send are as follows:

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth_signature_method
- oauth_version
- oauth_token
- oauth_verifier

I also add in the oauth_signature which is a signed version of all of those keys. I sign the request with the following method:

```
public void function signRequest(any req){
  var params = Arguments.req.getAllParameters();
  var secret = "#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(getConsumer().getConsumerSecret())#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getOAuthSecret())#";
  var base = '';

  params = Variables.encoder.encodedParameter(params, true, true);

  secret = toBinary(toBase64(secret));

  local.mac = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Mac').getInstance('HmacSHA1');
  local.key = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec').init(secret, local.mac.getAlgorithm());

  base = "#Arguments.req.getMethod()#&";
  base = base & Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getRequestUrl());
  base = "#base#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(params)#";

  local.mac.init(local.key);
  local.mac.update(JavaCast('string', base).getBytes());

  Arguments.req.addParameter('oauth_signature', toString(toBase64(mac.doFinal())), true);
}
```

I know that it works, because I can use the same method to request the initial token (without the oauth_token or oauth_verifier parameters), so I am assuming that it is a problem with the parameters that I am signing. (And yes I am alphabetically ordering the parameters before I sign them)

So is there a parameter that I shouldn't be including in the signature or another one that I should be?

This is an example of a base string that gets encrypted:

`POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fuas%2Foauth%2FaccessToken&oauth_consumer_key%3Dwfs3ema3hi9s%26oauth_nonce%3D1887241367210%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1331326503%26oauth_token%3D8b83142a-d5a6-452e-80ef-6e75b1b0ce18%26oauth_verifier%3D94828%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it was a stupid answer, but the problem was that I didn't see the oauth_token_secret come in when the user allowed access to my app, so I was still trying to sign the request using only the consumer secret and not both the consumer secret and oauth token secret.

Answer (score 1):

When sending a POST request, you need to put the authentication information in the header, not in the query parameters.

See this page for information (look for "Sending an Authorization Header"):
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/common-issues-oauth-authentication

I suspect this is the issue you're running into.

Comment: The issue was actually that I wasn't signing with both the consumer secret and the oauth token secret. You don't need to use the header until you are making requests to the API. Until you are done with the OAuth authentication, parameters can go into request parameters.